# Blog post comment reply with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem l need to create a comment reply action for my blog.

```
public JsonResult ReplyComment(string replycomment, int articleid, int commentid)
    {
        var UserId = Session["UserId"];
        if (replycomment == null)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        db.ReplyComments.Add(new ReplyComment
        { UserId = Convert.ToInt32(UserId), ArticleId=articleid, CommentId=commentid, Date = DateTime.Now, Paragraph = replycomment });
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(false,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is my ajax code but l have a problem here l cant reach commentid from Model and l need this variable for reply system

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#reply").click(function () {

        var usercomment = $("#replycomment").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ReplyComment/',
            data: { replycomment: usercomment, articleid:@Model.ArticleId, commentid:},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("yorum gönderildi" + usercomment);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

my article detail action

```
 public ActionResult ArticleDetail(int id)
    {
        var articles = db.Articles.Where(x => x.ArticleId == id).SingleOrDefault();

        if (articles == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(articles);
    }
```

so l need to send 2 model to ajax.data

Comment: *l cant reach commentid from Model* So, how do you send `Model` to the view?

Comment: l can reach Model.ArticleId    from Article Details Page but l cant reach comment id from article for ajax

Comment: You should add some more relevant code, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: l have a article details page. l am listing my blog posts and comments here l have no problem with database desing l am trying to create reply method with ajax and l need 3 variables you can see on first code  1= replycomment l can reach this  2 = articleid  l can reach this too on article details page  the last one is comment id  l can't reach this thing on ajax side  l hope you can understand me sorry for my english again.

Comment: I think you want to pass the comment ID from AJAX to code behind, but you didnt find the way how to get comment ID. If I understood correctly, then, As this is for reply to comment, whenever you are displaying the comment, you can have the comment id in the div or span whatever you are using to build the DOM. So that, when you click the #reply,  you can get the comment id and pass it to code behind.

Comment: post your html code, you can get the answer.

Comment: You understood me completly true   l think your idea will solve my problem l will try this when l go home thanks for answer and l will  let you know the result

Comment: can you give me an example how can have the comment id in a span for example <span id="getid">@item.commentId</span like this ?  $.("#getid").val();

Comment: It worked thanks now  l can get commentid

Comment: @GertArnold Sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to pass the comment ID from AJAX to code behind, but you didnt find the way how to get comment ID. If I understood correctly, then, As this is for reply to comment, whenever you are displaying the comment, you can have the comment id in the div or span whatever you are using to build the DOM. So that, when you click the #reply, you can get the comment id and pass it to code behind.